# How does math.min works

Tags: java

Giving two strings a and b. What does **int len = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());** do? Im a beginner and tried find math.min in API.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(double,%20double)

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(double,%20double))? Instead of wasting your time?

Comment: Isn't *"min"* descriptive enough to know what it does? Even without reading the documentation/javadoc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, if you're looking for documentation on any of the standard Java methods, check out [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). The specific documentation for `Math.min` is [available here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) and says

> Returns the smaller of two `int` values. That is, the result the argument closer to the value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. If the arguments have the same value, the result is that same value.

In your case, if you write

```
int len = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
```

it declares a variable called `len` of type `int` whose value is equal to the lesser of `a.length()` and `b.length()`. Effectively, it sets `len` equal to the length of the shorter of `a` and `b`.

Comment: That really helpful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Math.min returns whichever one is less than the other. In your case, since you are passing it the length of a, and the length of b, it is going to return the minimum of the two lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [JDK's implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l1335) of `Math.min()`,

```
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

Pretty much what it says on the tin. Reviewing the source code (if it's available!) for something you're using is a great way to get to know it.